# ASP.NET MVC: unity and HierarchicalLifeTimemanager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-container, lifetime

I have simple asp.net mvc application. I added unity to this project and tested different lifetime managers. I know that HierarchicalLifitemeManager is like ContainerControlledLifetimeManager (singletone) but unity creates different instances for each child unity container. I created class with single Guid property which is set in constructor, injected this class in controller using HierarchicalLifitemeManager  and show this Guid in view. And every time I press F5 I see new Guid. How does HierarchicalLifitemeManager work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine. 
You see different Guid because you create new root container for each request (F5).
Try to do this:

```
class HierarchicalService
{
    public Guid Value {get;set;}
    public HierarchicaService()
    {
        Value = Guid.Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}

register it:
...
container.RegisterType<HierarchicalService>(new HierarchicalLifitemeManager());
...

class MyController
{
    MyController(HierarchicalService serviceA, HierarchicalService serviceB)
    {
        //...compare values from both services
    }
}

And compare it with this:

class MyController
{
    MyController(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        var serviceA = container.CreateChildContainer().Resolve<HierarchicalService>();
        var serviceB = container.CreateChildContainer().Resolve<HierarchicalService>();
        //...compare values from both services
    }
}
```

So, difference is in case, when you have one root container and you need to separate some actions by creating new child containers with isolated scopes (UnitOfWorks, for example). Read more about [child containers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660895(v=pandp.20).aspx).

Comment: @oblomov86 did you try it?

Comment: Does unity create separate child container for each request for HierarchicalLifitemeManager?

Comment: @MaxQuestion no, you need to create child containers by yourself, but `Unity` cretates different instances from different child containers

Comment: I mean: using HierarchicalLifitemeManager we have new instance for each child container. So if each request has its own instance - each request has its own child container in this case. Am I rignt?